# how to speed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS bootloading time

Tags: grub2, bootloader

Good day fellas, I recently replaced windows 10 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS, now it is taking taking too long to boot. Below is the link I got after running boot-repair recommended settings http://paste2.org/tDJvhzU7
The time taken for the login screen to appear is about 50 seconds, I am using Hp 15 Notebook with RAM 4GB and HDD 1TB.
Thanks in advance.